# All layers missing in QGIS project - not 'Bad Layers' but simply gone

Tags: qgis

I have a QGIS project I have been using for several years for a large archaeological project. Today, on opening, all layers are missing - though the groups they were in are all present and the map composer is empty.

I do not get a Bad Layers prompt, they simply aren't present in the groups. Re-adding them works but I have several hundred with a whole host of layer styles, and dozens of maps, that I would need to work through.

Comment: Does anyone else have access to these projects? Have you saved any backups? Why haven't you saved the layer styles with your layers for this case?

Comment: No one else has access. I have managed to restore a version from last week - which opens fine - but I've still lost quite a lot of work. I don't know how to do so.

Comment: Go to the `properties` window of a layer, select the `symbology/style` tab, click `style` in the lower left corner, save the style (.qml-format) at the same location and with the same name as the corresponding shape-file.

Comment: Great. Thanks. Any thoughts on why the layers would all disappear?

Comment: The usual: Faulty saving, other data corruption, someone messing with your data, human error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem last week.  Using QGIS 2.18, half of the layers where missing.  No warnings.

And I am sure I did save it the right way, no one else opened it, etc.

The only thing that helped me: **backup**!